# How write hibernate criteria for specific SQL?

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, nhibernate-criteria

i need write similar SQL by ICriteria:

Tables:

1Lvl -- 2Lvl -- 3Lvl

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM 2Lvl
WHERE 2Lvl.1LvlFK in
(
    SELECT 1Lvl.Id

    FROM 3Lvl 

    JOIN 2Lvl ON 3Lvl.2LvlFK = 2Lvl.Id 

    JOIN 1Lvl ON 2Lvl.1LvlFK = 1Lvl.Id  

    WHERE 3Lvl.Id = 123
)
```

I'm sorry for so specific question, but I inherited project with Hibernate from exemployee and I can't still understand hibernate-criteria.

Comment: Do you need an ICriteria or HQL ?

Comment: Can you also post the mappings ?

Comment: 3Lvl has reference to 2Lvl by FK and 2Lvl has reference to 1Lvl by FK. There are no XML mapping, it use automapper, it is fluent NHibernate.

Comment: In Lvl1 class is list of LvL2. In Lvl2 class is list of Lvl3 and one Lvl1 item. In Lvl3 class is Lvl2 item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var subQuery = DetachedCriteria.For<Lvl3>("lvl3")
     .CreateAlias("Lvl2", "sublvl2", JoinType.InnerJoin)
     .CreateAlias("Lvl1", "lvl1", JoinType.InnerJoin)
     .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("sublvl2.Id", "lvl2.Id")
     .Add(Restrictions.Eq("lvl3.Id", 123)
     .SetProjection(Projections.Property("lvl1.Id"));

Session.CreateCriteria<Lvl2>("lvl2")
     .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Lvl1.Id", subQuery));
```

Should do the trick. I've made assumptions about what your entities are called since 1Lvl, etc.. are not valid C# identifiers. I've also assumed the primary key column of each table was Id. Also a note that this won't produce the exact SQL you're looking for, but it will get you the same result.

Comment: Thank you. Incorrect names of classes was just abstraction. Real name are Switch, SwitchBoard, ServerRoom etc. and there are more then 3 levels.